# Toilet bowl filling with water prior to normal flush

Tags: plumbing

Water was turned off for about 8 hours.  When the water was turned back on, the toilet began to flush up, the bowl is filling with water before the water goes down. I have use the plunger and it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Does the toilet have a cistern in back of it? Was the cistern full when turning on the water. If not water will flow filling the cistern, it will also put some water into the bowl as it is designed to do. If this does not help post a picture of what you have.

Comment: What does "toilet began to flush up" mean, exactly? The bowl will _always_ fill up a bit with water before it breaks over the trap and sucks everything down. Maybe you're just noticing it more because you weren't paying any particular attention prior to turning the water off/on?